# Count the number of non-null values in each column of each table in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to produce this output using SQL for all tables in a given database (using MySQL) without having to specify individual table names and columns?

```
Table   Column  Count
----    ----    ----
Table1  Col1    0
Table1  Col2    100
Table1  Col3    0
Table1  Col4    67
Table1  Col5    0
Table2  Col1    30
Table2  Col2    0
Table2  Col3    2
... ... ...
```

The purpose is to identify columns for analysis based on how much data they contain (a significant number of columns are empty).

The 'workaround' solution using python (one table at a time):

```
    # Libraries
    import pymysql
    import pandas as pd
    import pymysql.cursors

    # Connect to mariaDB
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='my_password',
                                 db='my_database',
                                 charset='latin1',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


    # Get column metadata
    sql = """SELECT *
                FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
                WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='my_database' 
            """
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute(sql)
      result = cursor.fetchall()

    # Store in dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df = df[['TABLE_NAME', 'COLUMN_NAME']]

    # Build SQL string (one table at a time for now)
    my_table = 'my_table'
    df_my_table = df[df.TABLE_NAME==my_table].copy()
    cols = list(df_my_table.COLUMN_NAME)
    col_strings = [''.join(['COUNT(', x, ') AS ', x, ', ']) for x in cols]
    col_strings[-1] = col_strings[-1].replace(',','')
    sql = ''.join(['SELECT '] + col_strings + ['FROM ', my_table])

    # Execute
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
```

The result is a dictionary of column names and counts.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. See also [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151855/count-null-values-of-table-from-information-schema-tables).

Also, note that the closest match of the answer above is actually the method you're already using, but less efficiently implemented in reflective SQL.

I'd do the same as you did - build a SQL like

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `count`,
    SUM(IF(columnName1 IS NULL,1,0)) AS columnName1,
    ...
    SUM(IF(columnNameN IS NULL,1,0)) AS columnNameN
FROM tableName;
```

using information_schema as a source for table and column names, then execute it for each table in MySQL, then disassemble the single row returned into N tuple entries (tableName, columnName, total, nulls).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it's not going to be quick.

As mentioned in a previous answer you can work your way through the columns table in the information_schema to build queries to get the counts. It's then just a question of how long you are prepared to wait for the answer because you end up counting every row, for every column, in every table. You can speed things up a bit if you exclude columns that are defined as NOT NULL in the cursor (i.e. IS_NULLABLE = 'YES').

The solution suggested by LSerni is going to be much faster, particularly if you have very wide tables and/or high row counts, but would require more work handling the results.

e.g.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS non_nulls //
CREATE PROCEDURE non_nulls (IN sname VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN

-- Parameters:
-- Schema name to check
-- call non_nulls('sakila');

  DECLARE vTABLE_NAME varchar(64);
  DECLARE vCOLUMN_NAME varchar(64);
  DECLARE vIS_NULLABLE varchar(3);
  DECLARE vCOLUMN_KEY varchar(3);

  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `COLUMN_NAME`, `IS_NULLABLE`, `COLUMN_KEY` 
    FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = sname
    ORDER BY `TABLE_NAME` ASC, `ORDINAL_POSITION` ASC;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS non_nulls;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE non_nulls(
    table_name VARCHAR(64),
    column_name VARCHAR(64),
    column_key CHAR(3),
    is_nullable CHAR(3),
    rows BIGINT, 
    populated BIGINT 
  ); 

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO vTABLE_NAME, vCOLUMN_NAME, vIS_NULLABLE, vCOLUMN_KEY;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

     SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO non_nulls ',
                '(table_name,column_name,column_key,is_nullable,rows,populated) ',
                'SELECT \'', vTABLE_NAME, '\',\'', vCOLUMN_NAME, '\',\'', vCOLUMN_KEY, '\',\'', 
                 vIS_NULLABLE, '\', COUNT(*), COUNT(`', vCOLUMN_NAME, '`) ',
                'FROM `', sname, '`.`', vTABLE_NAME, '`');

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;

  SELECT * FROM non_nulls;

END //

DELIMITER ;

call non_nulls('sakila');
```